# Whats a good java debugger?

Tags: java, performance, debugging, memory, memory-leaks

I'm trying to find memory leaks and performance issues with my java application. Is there a program out there that can help me debug my application and display performance results?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you currently using that is not suiting your needs?

Comment: Eclipse. I'm trying to use a memory plugin but I just cannot get it to work. So I'm looking for a more professional application rather than a simple plugin.

Comment: You might want to change your title to "What's a good Java profiler?" -- since traditional debuggers are usually better suited to diagnosing control-flow and logic bugs, while *profilers* are better suited to diagnosing memory leaks and performance issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at jvisualvm in the JDK - a subset of the Netbeans profiler -  which can attach to a running Java 6 process and allow you to profile it and do memory analysis.

https://visualvm.dev.java.net/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Yes. JVisualVM is absolutely the best tool for visualizing and debugging memory leaks in Java.

Comment: Not necessarily, but being part of the JDK makes it a good starting place.

Comment: @Kyle, you are welcome.  There are more tools in the JDK which are nice to know, but they are more low level than visualvm.

Answer (score 1):

I used a lot of tools to find why my program eats 100+ Mb of ram, polished the code to remove any possible memory leaks. Later I found that once jvm took some memory from the OS, I doesn't always return it, even if that memory is not used, which often looks like a memory leak. This depends on -Xmx and -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio. I set Xmx to 40 which is roughly how much memory my app should use, and memory usage stays within 10-15 Mb of this range instead of increasing uncontrollably.

Also, [jconsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) is a great tool. It comes with jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a good memory dump analyzer; but finding a memory leak can be very challenging and requires you to dive deeply into the way the objects are allocated by your application.

It took me 2 full days to figure out that one of my custom JTable cell editor classes was allocating a JDialog upon instantiation, without actually opening it, and the native part of the dialog kept the cell editor instance locked, thus the table, thus the screen and thus all entity objects that were associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try performance inspector tool.Following is the URL.

http://perfinsp.sourceforge.net/

Java Application performance is directly proportional to how JVM is running your application. This tool gives very good profiling information about JVM.But its not a graphical tool,you need to go through the text file generated. But its one time effort and you can get handy with this tool.I used it many time for performance related issues and it helped me lot.